# Dynamically updating a variable in For loop?

Tags: .net, excel, vba

I am trying to create a loop that cycles through rows and: (a) refreshes the variable when triggered by a new cell value in the looped column, or (b) updates its value when a condition is met and brings that into the next iteration of the loop.

My Excel table looks basically like this:

```
Header  commit  Avail   Comment
SKU1    6       5       Over
SKU1    3       5       Not Over (2 remaining)
SKU1    3       5       Over
SKU1    2       5       Not Over (0 remaining)
SKU1    3       5       Over
SKU1    3       5       Over
SKU2    3       4       Not Over (1 remaining)
SKU2    2       4       Over
```

Any help is appreciated. Here's what I have so far. The issue I'm having is that it doesn't seem to store the update value when it goes into the next loop iteration (AvailableInv = AvailableInv - LineCommit) :

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
Dim max As Integer
Dim PrevSKU As String
Dim CurrSKU As String
Dim AvailableInv As Integer
Dim LineCommit As Integer
Dim loopct As Integer

PrevSKU = Worksheets("New").Cells(2, "A").Value
AvailableInv = Worksheets("New").Cells(2, "C").Value
max = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For loopct = 2 To max

    CurrSKU = Worksheets("New").Cells(loopct, "A").Value
    LineCommit = Worksheets("New").Cells(loopct, "B").Value

    If CurrSKU <> PrevSKU Then
        AvailableInv = Worksheets("New").Cells(loopct, "C").Value
    Else
        PrevSKU = Worksheets("New").Cells(loopct - 1, "A").Value
    End If

    If LineCommit >= AvailableInv Then
        Worksheets("New").Cells(loopct, "D").Value = "Over"
    Else
        AvailableInv = AvailableInv - LineCommit
        Worksheets("New").Cells(loopct, "D").Value = "Not Over (" & AvailableInv & " remaining)"
    End If


Next loopct
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is a table like this, you could follow the code after the table:

```
Header  commit  Avail   Comment
SKU1    1       5       Not Over (4 remaining)
SKU1    3       5       Not Over (1 remaining)
SKU1    3       5       Over
SKU1    2       5       Over
SKU1    3       5       Over
SKU1    3       5       Over
SKU2    3       4       Not Over (1 remaining)
SKU2    2       4       Over
```

The code example:

```
    Sub Macro1()
    '
    ' Macro1 Macro
    '
    Dim max As Integer
    Dim PrevSKU As String
    Dim CurrSKU As String
    Dim AvailableInv As Integer
    Dim LineCommit As Integer
    Dim loopct As Integer

    PrevSKU = Worksheets("New").Cells(2, "A").Value
    AvailableInv = Worksheets("New").Cells(2, "C").Value
    max = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    For loopct = 2 To max

        CurrSKU = Worksheets("New").Cells(loopct, "A").Value
        LineCommit = Worksheets("New").Cells(loopct, "B").Value

        If loopct > 2 Then PrevSKU = Worksheets("New").Cells(loopct - 1, "A").Value

        If CurrSKU <> PrevSKU Then
            AvailableInv = Worksheets("New").Cells(loopct, "C").Value
             Debug.Print ("Loop:" & loopct & "   CuuSKU:" & CurrSKU & "    PrevSKU:" & PrevSKU & "    Available:" & AvailableInv)
        End If


        AvailableInv = AvailableInv - LineCommit

        If AvailableInv < 1 Then
            Worksheets("New").Cells(loopct, "D").Value = "Over"
        Else

            Worksheets("New").Cells(loopct, "D").Value = "Not Over (" & AvailableInv & " remaining)"
        End If


    Next loopct
End Sub
```

Basically you have some logic errors in the macro. Another suggestion is to use `Dubug.Print` to output the variables and check them.